# Send smtp mail with no authentication using php

Tags: php, html, css, smtp

I am trying to send an e-mail from a form using smtp with no authentication... Please help.
I called the hosting company and they told me that I should do it without authentication. I believe it would've been easier if I authenticated it.  Here is the code I have written below.

```
function ProcessForm($values){
include('smtpConfig.php');
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$to = 'mail';
$from = 'fromMail';
$subject = 'Website Contact';
$text     = $values['text'];
$name     = $values['name'];
$email    = $values['email'];  
$body = "
<style>

  * {
    font-family: verdana, helvetia, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }


  table {
    width: 600px;
    background:  #fff;
    margin: auto;
    border: #a9ee17 solid 4px;
  }

  table tr td {
    font-family: verdana, helvetia, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
</style>

A message has been sent from site. Its details are as follows:
<br/>
<br/>
<table cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <th><b>Field</b></th>
    <th><b>Value</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='row'>
    <td><b>Name</b></td>
    <td>$name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='row'>
    <td><b>Email Address</b></td>
    <td>$email</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='row'>
    <td><b>Message</b></td>
    <td>$text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
";
$SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
$SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
echo '<h2 class="center success">Your message was sent. Thank you very much</h2>';
  include_once 'static/contact-details.php';
}
}
```

The smtpConfig code below was initially setup to accept an stmp username and password, but since I am trying to use the smtp without any authentication, I removed the bits about the username and password and only left the smtpServer and the Port... The default port number is normally 25, as a default, so I'd like to assume this is not the issue here.

```
<?php

//Server Address
$SmtpServer="smtp.host.co.za";
$SmtpPort="25"; //default

class SMTPClient
{

function SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $from, $to, $subject, $body)
{

$this->SmtpServer = $SmtpServer;
$this->from = $from;
$this->to = $to;
$this->subject = $subject;
$this->body = $body;

if ($SmtpPort == "") 
{
$this->PortSMTP = 25;
}
else
{
$this->PortSMTP = $SmtpPort;
}
}

function SendMail ()
{
if ($SMTPIN = fsockopen ($this->SmtpServer, $this->PortSMTP)) 
{
fputs ($SMTPIN, "EHLO ".$HTTP_HOST."\r\n"); 
$talk["hello"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 );  
fputs ($SMTPIN, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->from.">\r\n"); 
$talk["From"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 ); 
fputs ($SMTPIN, "RCPT TO: <".$this->to.">\r\n"); 
$talk["To"] = fgets ($SMTPIN, 1024); 
fputs($SMTPIN, "DATA\r\n");
$talk["data"]=fgets( $SMTPIN,1024 );
fputs($SMTPIN, "To: <".$this->to.">\r\nFrom: <".$this->from.">\r\nSubject:".$this-       >subject."\r\n\r\n\r\n".$this->body."\r\n.\r\n");
$talk["send"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
//CLOSE CONNECTION AND EXIT ... 
fputs ($SMTPIN, "QUIT\r\n"); 
fclose($SMTPIN); 
// 
} 
return $talk;
 } 
}
?>
```

The code processes with no error but still does not send the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting company is talking about a parameter

```
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = MAIL_AUTENTIC;              // enable SMTP autenticacion
```

MAIL_AUTENTIC should be True or False to enable or not. In your case False

Some variables has been defined previosly, like:

```
define('MAIL_AUTENTIC', true);
```

Here an example with PHPMailer

```
include('includes/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //  true for exceptions in erors (try/catch)

$mail->IsSMTP();                        

try {                                                       

    $mail->Host       = MAIL_HOST;                  // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                          // SMTP debug 2 active 1 no active
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = MAIL_AUTENTIC;              // enable SMTP autenticacion
    $mail->Port       = MAIL_PUERTO;                // SMTP port
    $mail->Username   = MAIL_USUARIO;               // SMTP user
    $mail->Password   = MAIL_PASSWORD;              // SMTP password
    $mail->AddReplyTo('ccccc@mydomain.net', 'Envios');          // Reply address

    $mail->AddAddress($TO);
    $mail->SetFrom('Myfrom@mydomain.net', 'Bla bla');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('MyReply@mydomain.net', 'REsponse bla bla');
    $mail->Subject = $SUBJ;
    $mail->AltBody = 'Use HTML';        // optional 

    $mail->CharSet="utf-8";

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->MsgHTML($MYTEXT);

    $mail->Send();

} 
catch (phpmailerException $e) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

}
```